# Rails 4 Heroku Deployment The Page Doesn't Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I have a basic rails app contains nothing but Welcome controller and Index action.Which both empty.I have defined a root route to it.And deployed to heroku.Bu i get "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." this error message.My url is `"https://murmuring-island-27368.herokuapp. c o m/`".(Please delete the spaces from c o m ).Btw i tried running production env on local but it says "Internal Server Error

Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`".So what should i do?

This is the gem file.

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate new secret key, Try

```
rake secret
```

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: It got SOLVED.I take out " production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>" this part from config/secrets.yml to .gitignore. And it did the trick.Thank you all.